# widget example of actionbutton in shiny doesn't work

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I'm playing around with shiny, and can't get the simplest action button example to work.

First example found here:http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/widgets-gallery.html

Below are the code, which is a copy paste from the website.

```
#ui.R
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Copy the line below to make an action button
  actionButton("action", label = "Action"),

  hr(),
  fluidRow(column(2, verbatimTextOutput("value")))

))


#server.R
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # You can access the value of the widget with input$action, e.g.
  output$value <- renderPrint({ input$action })

})
```

Mine looks like:
http://imgur.com/t0Vx6Wr

edit:
The issue is that it also prints out some class information
Thanks

Comment: Looks like its working to me. Everytime you press the button the counter increments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `renderText` rather then `renderPrint` if you want it to look like it does on the `shiny` website:

```
require(shiny)
runApp(list(ui = fluidPage(
  actionButton("action", label = "Action"),
  hr(),
  fluidRow(column(2, verbatimTextOutput("value")))
)
, server = function(input, output) {
  output$value <- renderText({ input$action })  
})
)
```

[image]